# n3-line-chart: Inconsistent values for dates on x axis

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, linechart

I'm creating a line chart using [n3 line chart](https://github.com/n3-charts/line-chart) in my angular app.
My data is array of dates and counts.
This is the result I get:

[image]

As you can see, the X axis values are inconsistent.
It has a tick every 12 hours, but each tick has different format. I'm trying to keep the format the same for every tick, i.e:

[image]

This is how I include the chart in my html:

```html
<linechart class="linechart" data="data" options="options"></linechart>
```

This is my axes options:

```
    $scope.options = {
        axes: {
            x: {
                key: "from",
                type: "date",
                innerTicks: false,
                grid: false,
                ticksInterval: d3.time.days
            },
            y: {
                ticks: 6,
                ticksFormatter: $scope. formatNumber
            }
        }
```

I've tried to use diffent values for `ticks` and `ticksInterval` but with no success.

Any way to achieve this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem today.

I solved it using thickFormat and the [d3.time.format()](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Formatting) function.

```
axes : {
                    x : {
                        key : "date",
                        type : 'date',
                        tickFormat : d3.time.format("%x %X")
                    }
                }
```

Comment: But then your format wil be always the same, right? I mean if I have 2 datasets, one with a year range, and another with just one day. Then I need the first one to show weeks or months, and the second to show minutes or hours. but in any case the format should be consistent.